# Resizing CAShapeLayer

Tags: objective-c, uiview, resize, cashapelayer

I have a simple test app on which my rootViewController's UIView contains a bunch of UIView subviews. Each one of those UIView subview is backed by a CAShapeLayer.

I want the [composition](http://i49.tinypic.com/dfdmjn.jpg) created by those subviews ( the four shapes that are within the dotted area .. ) to always stay vertically and horizontally centered with respect to my
UIWindow. (the minimium size of the left/right, top/bottom margins will be subject to be changed at runtime at each orientation change )

So for example when i rotate to [portrait](http://i50.tinypic.com/2nkuxr4.jpg) i will have to
resize and reposition those single shapes so that the whole figure will be mantained centered and each CAShapeLayer sublayer stays sharp ( i want their path to be resized not just a raster resize )

what would be the best technique to resize/move the shapes to always have a centered composition while maintaining path crisp appearance for the shapes?

Ultimately for me it will be good to have an answer to this: how can i shrink the subviews as a whole? i mean their sizes and relative positions?

Thanks

Comment: Did you figure it out? Do you use a transform? And if, how does it look like?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CGPathCreateMutableCopyByTransformingPath()` or `-[UIBezierPath applyTransform:]` to recalculate all points in the path.